Compressed NFT with attributes
Is there a way to add attributes in metadata to compressed NFT?

cNFT data is in the ledger and needs to be indexed. I dont think you can add on chain attributes there.
You can do that though using meta data Token Extension:
    invoke_signed(
        &spl_token_metadata_interface::instruction::update_field(
            &spl_token_2022::id(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key,
            ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().key,
            spl_token_metadata_interface::state::Field::Key("level".to_string()),
            "1".to_string()
        ),
        &[
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().clone(),
        ],
        signer
    )?;

You can update these fields in your program easily and immidiatelly see them in the solana explorers.
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/token-2022/nft-meta-data-pointer/anchor-example

Did you try to add them to the JSON uploaded and pasted in the URI field?
import { none } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import { mintV1 } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum'

await mintV1(umi, {
  leafOwner,
  merkleTree,
  metadata: {
    name: 'My Compressed NFT',
    uri: 'https://example.com/my-cnft.json',  // TODO: in this json
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500, // 5%
    collection: none(),
    creators: [
      { address: umi.identity.publicKey, verified: false, share: 100 },
    ],
  },
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)


Yes, this is trivial, but i wanted to add attribute fields on-chain

You cannot add on-chain attributes. You can store the metadata on immutable storage like Arweave so it can never be edited.
